# MSBuild Not Using All Package Feeds

Tags: msbuild, nuget, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to configure a build server (Windows Server 2019) to build a .NET Framework 4.7.2 VB.NET web service using GitLab CI. The project has a dependency on a NuGet package from a private feed (also hosted on GitLab). The GitLab runner is configured to use PowerShell as Local System. My script looks like this:

```
- nuget sources add -name "GitLab" -source "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/********/-/packages/nuget/index.json" -username "********" -password "********"; $null
- nuget sources list
- msbuild /restore /t:build /p:Configuration=Release
```

The first command executes successfully (the first time, and then fails silently if the source already exists). The second command correctly outputs:

```
Registered Sources:
  1.  GitLab [Enabled]
      https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/********/-/packages/nuget/index.json
  2.  NuGet.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

The msbuild command fails because it can't find the package. It says this:

```
Failed to restore D:\GitLab-Runner\builds\... (in 1.14 sec).
  
  NuGet Config files used:
      C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
  
  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Done Building Project "D:\GitLab-Runner\builds\..." (Restore target(s)) -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
```

I've confirmed that the above NuGet.config file contains the source. SDK-style C# projects (.NET Standard 2.1, .NET 6, .NET 7) all restore and build just fine using the `dotnet build` command. `dotnet build` does not work at all for this project; it says that "all projects are up-to-date for restore" but then has errors for all dependencies, not just the one from the private feed.

I don't know if any portions of the .vbproj file are relevant to this issue. I've attempted using `nuget restore` before msbuild and it returns the same error. If I log on to the server as an admin and add the source (it gets added to %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config) then I can use both MSBuild and NuGet.

Why does MSBuild fail to use the private feed for restoring packages when invoked by the Local System GitLab runner?

Comment: If you are expecting NuGet to check one feed and if the package is not found, cascade to checking the next feed, NuGet doesn't do that for http/s feeds. Use just one http/s feed at a time. (I suspect there is a defect and/or a missing feature with respect to NuGet.) Either configure the private feed to up-source to NuGet.org and ensure that only the private feed is registered, or run separate restore steps for each feed.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I was able to get this working with separate restore steps. My SDK-style projects regularly restore from NuGet.org and our GitLab feed without any issues, and as far as I know Visual Studio has no problems restoring packages from both when building these .NET Framework projects locally, so it's weird that this is a "gotcha" in seemingly only this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Per Jonathan Dodds's advice I changed my script to this:

```
- msbuild /restore /p:RestoreConfigFile="D:\NuGet\GitLab.config"; $null
- msbuild /restore /t:build /p:Configuration=Release
```

The specified config file contains just the GitLab NuGet source. The `; $null` is required as the command still fails, but the second command succeeds. I encountered additional issues where the downloaded packages weren't being saved to disk, and the solution there was to change the GitLab runner service to run as my admin user account and not Local System. That's definitely not ideal in the long run.

My main takeaway from this is to upgrade to SDK-style projects whenever possible. I've never had issues with the `dotnet build` command, whereas using MSBuild for these .NET Framework projects has been a pain.